# How to check datetime in C

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int main(void) {
        struct tm str_time;
        time_t time_of_day;

        str_time.tm_year = 2012-1900;
        str_time.tm_mon = 6;
        str_time.tm_mday = 5;
        str_time.tm_hour = 10;
        str_time.tm_min = 3;
        str_time.tm_sec = 5;
        str_time.tm_isdst = 0;

        time_of_day = mktime(&str_time);
        printf(ctime(&time_of_day));

        return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly, but I can't find a way to verify that the date and time are in the code is the same as the computer, does anyone have any idea of how to compare both dates?

Comment: The `time()` function returns the system's view of the current time: `time_t now = time(0);` and you can then analyze that with `localtime()` to obtain the broken down time.  For parsing date strings, consider `strptime()`.

Comment: I think I explained wrong I want to compare my date with the current date of my computer. e.g. `if (mydatetime == datetimenow) printf (your datetime is equal to computer)`

Comment: Well, if your computer still thinks it is July 2012 (note that months are 'off by one'), you've got problems.  I'm afraid your 'clarification' comment is inscrutable; I am none the wiser after reading it.

Comment: The fact of using 2012 was just an example, I want to do is check a future date and time, I need to compare my date with the current date from your computer. E.g. `2016-06-25 06:58:31`, the day you arrive at that date and time I want to pull a function, the problem is that I wanted to know how to compare dates

Comment: `strptime` is not in ISO C, you may need to download a freeware implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... have any idea of how to compare both dates?

OP is doing 3 things that contribute to potential time differences.

1. Code may not have filled all needed fields before calling `mktime(&str_time);`.  C specifies at least 9 fields.  Best to zero-fill `str_time` and then set the 7 fields.  This is relatively a rare problem.
2. OP comments about date "2016-06-25 06:58:31".  Yet does not post the values use to populate `struct tm`.   A common mis-code is that `tm_mon` is the months since January, so a minus 1 is needed.

   ```
   str_time.tm_year = 2016-1900;
   str_time.tm_mon = 6 - 1;
   str_time.tm_mday = 25;
   str_time.tm_hour = 6;
   str_time.tm_min = 58;
   str_time.tm_sec = 31;
   str_time.tm_isdst = tbd; // see below
   ```
3. `str_time.tm_isdst = 0;`  sets the timestamp to no daylight-savings-time.  Often it is better to use `str_time.tm_isdst = -1;` and let the system determine if DST was in effect.

Rather than compute the `time_t` for a given user year-month-day, recommend to take the computer's time and convert that to year-month-day and then compare.  Certainly any differences / discrepancies will be easier to understand.

To compare the computer local year-moth-day to user input

```
// February 20, 2016
int y = 2016;
int m = 2;
int d = 20;

time_t now;
if (time(&now) == -1) Handle_Error();
struct tm *tm = localtime(&now);
if (tm == NULL) Handle_Error();

if (((tm->tm_year + 1900) == y) && ((tm->tm_mon + 1) == m) && (tm->tm_mday == d)) {
  puts("Dates match");
}
```

Comment: It's just always so darn rare to find good "deviations" in code posted by that guy chux... (we'll take care of it)